# fetch a attribute form Next & Prev div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying out a example to learn how to fetch attribute "href" of "a tag" from next & prev div's. Consider i click on the 'a tag' in the div id="rw2", i need to get the href of a tag in the prev div#rw1 and next div#rw3.

```
  <div class="plist" id="rw1">
    <div class="image">
         <a href="1.html">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="some"></div>
    <div class="few"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="plist" id="rw2">
    <div class="image">
         <a href="2.html">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="some"></div>
    <div class="few"></div>
  </div>

   <div class="plist" id="rw3">
    <div class="image">
         <a href="3.html">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="some"></div>
    <div class="few"></div>
  </div>

   ......
```

expect result  when

```
#rw1 .image a clicked - next = '2.html' & Prev = ''

#rw2 .image a clicked - next = '3.html' & Prev = '1.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".plist .image a").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).closest(".plist").prev(".plist").find("a").prop("href");
    var n = $(this).closest(".plist").next(".plist").find("a").prop("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you are looking for, check console on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/BttMH/1/ :

```
$(".plist .image a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //to stop page from loading - can remove depending on need
    var $plist = $(this).closest(".plist");
    var thisId = $plist.prop("id");
    var nextLink = $plist.next().find("a").prop("href") || "";
    var prevLink = $plist.prev().find("a").prop("href") || "";
    console.log(thisId + ".image a clicked - next = '"+nextLink+"' & Prev = '"+prevLink+"'");
});
```

**Edit:** to get your exact desired results try this: http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/BttMH/3/

```
$(".plist .image a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //to stop page from loading - can remove depending on need
    var $plist = $(this).closest(".plist");
    var thisId = $plist.prop("id");
    var nextLink = $plist.next().find("a").prop("href") || "";
    var prevLink = $plist.prev().find("a").prop("href") || "";
    nextLink = nextLink.substr(nextLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //remove these if you want full url
    prevLink = prevLink.substr(prevLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(thisId + " .image a clicked - next = '"+nextLink+"' & Prev = '"+prevLink+"'");
});
```

clicking through will log:

```
rw1 .image a clicked - next = '2.html' & Prev = ''
rw2 .image a clicked - next = '3.html' & Prev = '1.html'
rw3 .image a clicked - next = '' & Prev = '2.html'
```